# boto3 and aiobotocore version issue

Tags: asynchronous, boto3

To use aiobotocore we need boto3 == 1.24.59,
Because aioboto3 (10.1.0) depends on aiobotocore (2.4.0)
and aiobotocore (2.4.0) depends on boto3 (>=1.24.59,<1.24.60), aioboto3 (10.1.0) requires boto3 (>=1.24.59,<1.24.60).

Why aiobotocore does not support latest version of boto3.